# Can anyone tell me, how can i include lines behind the text

Tags: css

Is it possible to include line like this behind the text?

[image]

Comment: You can use pseudo-elements `::after` or `::before`.

Comment: But with the ::after ::before property, the line will work like a border.. for example it can be just under the whole text, not individualy in every line.. I need to make that background in every single line, that means if line increase the background will also increase and there will be the separation like the paragraph

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I did it using styled components **without** sudo elements:

```js
export const LineBehind = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  color: black;

  span {
    /* background: #fff; */  # un-comment to wrap line around text (not thru)
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
`
```

Ends up looking like this [image]

So in your case, you could increase the border size and change the color to achieve the desired result

Comment: No i dont want like this.